# How to move tableview up when some particular textfield are hidden by keyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, tableview

I am having a tableview with textfield present in the tableview cell's.when i try to enter text particularly in Textfield present at the bottom of tableview,then textfields are hidden with keyboard.
I am trying to solve this problem by using code present below.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyBoardWillChange(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyBoardWillChange(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyBoardWillChange(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)
    }

   @objc func keyBoardWillChange(notification : Notification)
    {
        print("Keyboard will show :\(notification.name.rawValue)")
        let cell = deliveryTableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath.init(row: 8, section: 0))
        
        view.frame.origin.y = -175
    }/*
    @objc func KeyBoardWillHide(notification : Notification)
    {
        UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 0.25, delay: 0.0, options: UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions.allowUserInteraction, animations: {
            self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height)
        }, completion: nil)
    }*/
    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIResponder.keyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)
    }
```

But the problem is that tableview shift upward even when clicking on very first textfield,which does not looks good .But i want tableview to shift upward only in case of textfield's present at the bottom.

Comment: Try using [https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager). This lib may be help you

Comment: Thanks.I will try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **IQKeyboardManager** with just single line of code in appdelegate.It will take care of keyboard.

**step 1)** Add pod 'IQKeyboardManager' in pod-file and run **pod install**

**step 2)**  Enable IQKeyboardManager by writing this piece of code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method of appdelegate

IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true

Refrence: https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager